# How to regexp_replace the first occurrence of decimal if there's more than one in bigquery/googlesql

Tags: google-bigquery, regexp-replace

This is what I have currently, trying to clean a messy string value to only have numbers. Everything else is fine, just the issue now is that the REGEX_REPLACE is moving all decimals. When there is more than one decimal, I want to remove the first occurrence only.

```
TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(CASE
  WHEN column = "-" THEN "0"
  WHEN column = "o" THEN "0"
  WHEN column IS NULL THEN "0"
  WHEN column LIKE '%o%' THEN REPLACE (column, 'o','0')
  WHEN column LIKE '%,%' THEN REPLACE (column, ',', '.')
  WHEN column LIKE '%,%' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(column, r'\.', '')
  WHEN column LIKE '%/%' THEN "0"
  WHEN column LIKE '%kg%' THEN REPLACE (column, 'kg', '')
  WHEN LENGTH(column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column, '.', '')) = 1 THEN column
  WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, 'n') IS NOT NULL THEN "0"
  WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, 'tb') IS NOT NULL THEN "0"
  WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, 'REF') IS NOT NULL THEN "0"
  ELSE column
  END,r's/.//', '')) AS Column
```

I tried a few other REGEX methods but due to lack of understanding it wasn't giving the desired outcome.

An example of this query running is below

Input is the column I'm querying, and output is the result of the query being run against the column. The desired output is what I want as a result of the query. This is being achieved for all rows apart from rows 2 and 5, this is where there are multiple occurrences of decimals, and I'm trying to remove only the first occurrence only

```
ID  | Input     |Output     |Desired Output
1   | 45988,8   |45988.8    |45988.8
2   | 45.856,90 |45.856.90  |45856.90
3   | 457.88    |457.88     |457.88
4   | 456,788   |456.788    |456.788
5   | 123.45.67 |123.45.67  |12345.67
6   | 45 kg     |45         |45
7   | tbc       |0          |0
8   | na        |0          |0
9   | REF       |0          |0
```

Comment: provide example of your input data and expected output - and clearly illustrate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT id, input, 
  ( SELECT REVERSE(STRING_AGG(IF(OFFSET = 1, '.' || x, x), ''))
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REVERSE(input), r'[^0-9.,]', r''), ',','.'), '.')) x WITH OFFSET 
  ) output
FROM your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meaning you just want to extract numbers and .'s without any regard to any other character in the string using regexp_replace?  And, remove any double (or more) decimals?

How about something like this --

```
with sample as (
  select a
  from unnest(["384859ccad..9349","48,594...99%","394ffffbb$%%"]) as a
)
select cast(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a,"[.]{2,}","."),"[^0-9.]+","") as float64) as new_a
from sample
```

I broke this into 2 regex -- first one "[.]{2,}" is 2 or more decimals in a row, replaced with a single one, then the "[^0-9.]+" regex means everything but 0-9 set with . included.  Is that what you're aiming for?

Or did you mean multiple decimals throughout, and not in a row? In which case, how do you know which one to keep?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on this, and it does remove all of the other characters but I need it to remove only the first occurrence of a decimal should the string contain multiple decimals - is this possible?